# the boundary of set in euclidean space is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

MY Attempt: Let $\partial A$ be the boundary of any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. We show $R^n \setminus \partial A$ is open. Pick $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \subseteq \partial A $. Then by definition, we must either have for $r> 0$

$(1). B(x,r) \cap A = \varnothing $

$(2). B(x,r) \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A ) = \varnothing $

Suppose $(1).$ holds. Our goal is to find $R > 0$ such that $B(y, R) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \partial A $ for $y \in B(x,r) $. In particular, we must have $||x-y|| < r$. Now, pick $z \in B(y,R) \implies ||z-y|| < R $. Hence

$$ ||z - x || \leq ||z-y|| + ||y-x|| < R + r = \frac{3r}{2}$$

if we choose $R = \frac{r}{2} $. So, with this choice, we clearly see that $B(y, \frac{r}{2}) \subset B(x,r) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A $. In particular, we must have $B(y, \frac{r}{2} )\cap A = \varnothing $. Hence, $B(y \frac{r}{2}) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \partial A $. And we obtain what we want.

if $(2).$ holds, then we again can find $R >0$ such that $B(y,R) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \partial A $.

In any case, we have shown that $\partial A$ is closed.

Is this a correct solution? Can someone give some feedback? thank you very much

Comment: What exactly is the definition of $\partial A$ that you use here?

Comment: I don't think you really mean $\Bbb R^n\subseteq\partial A,$ do you? Perhaps $\Bbb R^n\setminus\partial A$ instead?

Comment: There are many equivalent definitions, but Munkres defines $\partial A = \overline{A}\cap\overline{X\setminus A}$, which is obviously closed in $X$ (being the intersection of two closed subsets of $X$). You must be working with another definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I assume here that you meant to say "Pick $x\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\partial A.$"]

Your approach is okay, but there are a few issues to fix.

First of all, since $x\notin\partial A,$ then we can say by definition that for *some* $r>0$ we have either $(1)$ or $(2)$. This need not hold for *all* $r>0,$ though, and you don't really make clear which you mean.

Second of all, we *want* to find some $R>0$ such that $B(x,R)\subseteq\Bbb R^n\setminus\partial A,$ meaning that we need $y\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\partial A$ whenever $\lVert x-y\rVert<R.$ I recommend putting $R=\frac{r}2,$ as then we can show that for all $y\in B(x,R),$ we have $B(y,R)\cap A=\emptyset$ if $(1)$ holds and $B(y,R)\cap(\Bbb R^n\setminus A)=\emptyset$ if $(2)$ holds, by applying triangle inequality. Hence, $y\in\Bbb R^n\setminus\partial A$ for all $y\in B(x,R),$ and so $B(x,R)\subseteq\Bbb R^n\setminus\partial A,$ as desired.

Comment: one question: So my choice $R = \frac{r}{2} $ does not work ?

Comment: It works just fine in the approach I outline above, but does not work in yours. You've shown that if $y\in B(x,r)$ and $z\in B(y,\frac r2),$ then $z\in B(x,\frac{3r}2),$ which is not enough to show that $B(y,\frac r2)\subseteq B(x,r).$ For an easy counterexample, let $x$ be the origin, $r=4$ and $y$ be any point a distance of $3$ along some axis from the origin. Then we can take $z=\frac32y.$ Then $y\in B(x,r),$ but $\lVert x-z\rVert=\frac92>4$ and $\lVert y-z\rVert=\frac32<2,$ so while $z\in B(y,\frac r2),$ we do *not* have $z\in B(x,r).$